# About using external libraries in one workspace

Tags: ros, libraries, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I have a Workspace baz and I want to figure out how to include more libraries, for example foo and bar to my Workspace baz and use it together.

The space for the libraries is /baz/src/roo/include

In this case, one of the libraries is `roslibjs` and I cloned it from git, but there is no CMakeList.txt or package.xml in it.
[roslibjs](http://github.com/RobotWebTools/roslibjs)

How does that work?

Thanks beforehand!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202361/about-using-external-libraries-in-one-workspace/) by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on ROS Answers with karma: 82 on 2015-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you followed the roslibjs [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/roslibjs)? Afaik, 'everything' is explained there (everything is in quotes, because it obviously assumes knowledge about ROS).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1